# Guessing Strategy With A Zero Frequency Option Eventually Leading To A Success?

Tags: probability

I have searched for guessing strategies, and the threads I have found conclude that no guessing strategy (e.g. guessing randomly, or only choosing certain options) increase the likelihood of guessing correctly on a multiple choice test greater than 1/n, (where n = the number of options on the question).

However, intuition tells me that in a situation where all options have the same likelihood of being chosen as a correct answer, and there is no bias (human-caused, or otherwise) in what options are chosen as a correct answer, one is almost certainly going to have at least one success (one correct answer, assuming the number of questions is large enough) by picking the option which at that point was the correct answer 0 times.

That is to say, in a 100-question multiple choice test, assuming the conditions stated above, if choice E (which is a valid answer choice), was not a correct answer for the first 99 questions, then it would almost surely be the correct answer for question number 100. (I do not know if a size of 100 is large enough in this case, but at least I feel like it is).

I do realize that this strategy assumes the answer to the question is given to you after you have selected your answer.

Comment: at the point where you face the last question the probability of every answer option is exactly 1/n (n being the number of answers to the last question) no matter what the other answers were

Comment: True, but if each question has a relatively small number of options to choose from as an answer, and each option is equally likely to be the answer, then that probability that option E is never chosen on a 100 question test is extremely unlikely if there is no bias. (It converges).

Comment: what converges? in which sense? What is your mathematical background?

Comment: If your reasoning worked for $n=100$, it should also work for $n=99$. Likewise for $n=98,\;n=97,\;...,\;n=2$. For $n=2$, you can experiment by flipping a coin. That experiment should dispel your superstition.

Comment: The probability that option E was never chosen for the first 99 questions is also extremely small, so if you apply Bayes' rule you'll find that the *conditional* probability is still $1/n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy